# EF Code First Migration throws StackOverflowException on Azure Web Role

Tags: entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-migrations, stack-overflow

The issue occurs when executing EF 6.1.2 code first migrations in an Azure Web Role (WS 2012 R2). The same migrations run fine locally, even if I point the connection string to the (Azure) Sql Database.

The StackOverflowException is thrown by Entity Framework code, and the first line of ANY of my migrations doesn´t even get hit.

I have tried running the migrations in three different ways:

```
DbMigrator migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
migrator.Update(); // Here the exception is thrown
```

second:

```
DbMigrator migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
pendingMigrations = migrator.GetPendingMigrations().ToList();
foreach (string pendingMigration in pendingMigrations)
{
    migrator.Update(pendingMigration); // Here the exception is thrown
}
```

and using web.config:

```
<contexts>
      <context type="Superb.WorkNextDoor.EFRepository.Context.WndDbContext, Superb.WorkNextDoor.EFRepository, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral">
        <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[Superb.WorkNextDoor.EFRepository.Context.WndDbContext, Superb.WorkNextDoor.EFRepository], [Superb.WorkNextDoor.EFRepository.Migrations.Migrations.WndDbMigrationsConfiguration, Superb.WorkNextDoor.EFRepository.Migrations]], EntityFramework">
        </databaseInitializer>
      </context>
    </contexts>
```

I see the StackOverflowException in Visual Studio when I´m remote debugging the web role. An error is recorded in windows event log of the web role (log info at the bottom of this post).

I have two migrations. I have tried running the first one from PMC and the second from the web role but no luck.

I have tried installing .Net 4.5.2 on the server, changing the VM size from XS to S and downgrading EF to version 6.1.1. Nothing worked. Also, I tried downloading the folder "E:\sites\0" from the web role to my local computer, installed the app on IIS and attached my VS Debugger and it doesn't throw that exception. There has got to be something different between my Windows 8.1 and that Windows Server 2012 R2.

I have spent a lot of time trying different things but I don´t want to give up on this and have to execute my migrations from package manager console.

> Log Name:      Application Source:        Application Error Date:
>   1/11/2015 3:21:42 AM Event ID:      1000 Task Category: (100) Level:
>   Error Keywords:      Classic User:          N/A Computer:
>   RD0003FF508F5B Description: Faulting application name: w3wp.exe,
>   version: 8.5.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x5215df96 Faulting module name:
>   clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.34014, time stamp: 0x52e0b86c Exception
>   code: 0xc00000fd Fault offset: 0x0000000000195499 Faulting process id:
>   0xc60 Faulting application start time: 0x01d02d4d77fdfb93 Faulting
>   application path: d:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe Faulting module
>   path: D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Report
>   Id: f5e4d6dc-9940-11e4-80bd-0003ff508f5b Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:  Event Xml: 
>   
>       
>       1000
>       2
>       100
>       0x80000000000000
>       
>       467
>       Application
>       RD0003FF508F5B
>             
>       w3wp.exe
>       8.5.9600.16384
>       5215df96
>       clr.dll
>       4.0.30319.34014
>       52e0b86c
>       c00000fd
>       0000000000195499
>       c60
>       01d02d4d77fdfb93
>       d:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
>       D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
>       f5e4d6dc-9940-11e4-80bd-0003ff508f5b

Easy steps to reproduce this error:

1. Download this sample project: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application
2. Add a CloudServiceProject to the solution and add the web project as a web role
3. Publish it to azure
4. Browse the web site and go to students tab (this hits the database and the initializer tries to execute the migrations).
5. Happens the same.

Comment: Tons of research effort, lots of relevant information, even a way to completely reproduce the issue. Only one upvote (mine). Crazy world...

Comment: @GertArnold Yes :/ strange that nobody came across this issue before. I had reported it on codeplex and it was assigned for investigation: [https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2637](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2637)

Comment: Possibly related: [Azure Cloud Service running Web Role (web application) memory issue (Gen2)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28022553/861716)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is identified as a bug in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Update 4. As a temporary work around disable "Lazy Initialization" under IntelliTrace Settings -> IntelliTrace Events. We are investigating fixing this bug in a future update for Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Thanks Rajkumar! Glad to receive an answer from the IntelliTrace team. I have tested your workaround and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

The responsible for the StackOverflowException turned out to be IntelliTrace. I don't know the root cause of the issue between IntelliTrace and Code First Migrations that cause this behavior but when I downloaded the IntelliTrace logs I could see a lot of Sql exceptions:

[image: IntelliTrace Summary 2/18/15]

I have already lost a lot of time with this so I won't investigate it further. The easiest workaround for me now is just disable IntelliTrace before deploying my Web Roles:

[image: Disable IntelliTrace]

If somebody is curious, here are the [IntelliTrace logs](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=782E71E9B77FB492!7365&authkey=!AGnVyOhnAmCdsTM&ithint=folder%2C).

I hope this helps someone else solve such a problem without losing as much time as I did.