# MSAL.Desktop.4.36.0.0.MsalServiceException: User canceled authentication 'ErrorCode: authentication_canceled' while running WPF on Windows Server 2016

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to read teams user status from WPF Desktop application. For that, I am using **Microsoft.Identity.Client - 4.36.0v, Microsoft.Identity.Client.Desktop-4.36.0v** to get token to access MS Graph api's.

My Application works perfectly in local machine which runs on Windows 10. When I moved the sources to VM which runs on Windows server 2016, It gives `'MsalServiceException: User canceled authentication'` on the below code. Account picker is blinking and vanishing. I haven't cancel anything.

```
authResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes) .WithAccount(accounts.FirstOrDefault()) .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount) .ExecuteAsync();

MSAL.Desktop.4.36.0.0.MsalServiceException: 
    ErrorCode: authentication_canceled
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: Broker response returned error: User canceled authentication. 
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Broker.BrokerInteractiveRequestComponent.ValidateResponseFromBroker(MsalTokenResponse msalTokenResponse)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Broker.BrokerInteractiveRequestComponent.<FetchTokensAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.<FetchTokensFromBrokerAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.<GetTokenResponseAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.<ExecuteAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Could you check Event Viewer -> Windows Logs?

Comment: Hi @user2250152, yes, i could see the below error "Faulting application name: Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin.exe, version: 10.0.14393.3143, time stamp: 0x5d3a7223
Faulting module name: AAD.Core.dll, version: 10.0.14393.3143, time stamp: 0x5d3a7253"

Comment: try to install the latest update for .net framework on your Windows Server

Comment: @user2250152 I could see the latest version of .net framework in registry. version-4.8.03761, Release-528049

Answer (score 0):

Please Check for these Possible work arounds

```
Msal exception
```

If the user closes the process or if they hit the browser back button, MSAL generates an error : authentication_canceled .

You may try inform the user when that happens :[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.msalerror.authenticationcancelederror?view=azure-dotnet)

Also see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43851228/azure-ad-authentication-error-user-cancelled-the-flow)

```
Error Faulting application name: ....
```

Reason for this error varies from one scenario to other. check few listed among them below.

Set `Enable 32-Bit Applications`:
If deploying a 32-bit (x86) app, set the value to `True` otherwise set it to false if it is 64 bit. [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-5.0#failed-to-start-application-errorcode-0x800700c1)

CHECK

If  You have latest Azure SDK and correct dll references. e.g. Make sure that if you have version 4.0, all references use same version. Remove any unnecessary references from the project.

1. All references (including packages and own libraries) are enabled with `"Copy Local" = True` and they are included in the package bin /assemblies.
2. Try to uninstall and reinstall packages from NuGet for ex: Azure Caching package
3. Check the connection strings and validity of keys, in case of storage.
4. Check whether **service configuration** has correct osFamily (ex :3) and osVersion that you are targeting in ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg are compatible

Otherwise  try intelliTrace.
Temporarily disable "Lazy Initialization" under IntelliTrace Settings -> IntelliTrace Events. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890028/ef-code-first-migration-throws-stackoverflowexception-on-azure-web-role)